# Kafka version sarama 2.6.0 smooth running on local but in staging error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, apache-kafka, sarama

This is my code I'm using `ibm/sarama`

```
    version, err := sarama.ParseKafkaVersion(version)
    if err != nil {
        boot.Logger.L.Critical(err.Error(), err)
        log.Panicf("Error parsing Kafka version: %v", err)
    }

    delayDuration := time.Millisecond * time.Duration(delay)
    log.Printf("Delaying Kafka consumption start by %v milliseconds", delay)
    time.Sleep(delayDuration)
```

But I have an error when I'm running with sarama `v2.6.0` on staging but in development running smoothly

```
2024/03/19 16:56:36 Starting a new Sarama consumer
2024/03/19 16:56:36 ++--------------------\[UP...\]--------------------++
2024/03/19 16:56:36 \[UP...\] - New Logger Slack connection successfully open
2024/03/19 16:56:36 \[UP...\] - New DB connection successfully open
2024/03/19 16:56:36 \[UP...\] - New Cache Redis connection successfully open
2024/03/19 16:56:36 \[UP...\] - New Queue Server successfully open
2024/03/19 16:56:36 \[UP...\] - New Queue Client successfully open
asynq: pid=1366 2024/03/19 16:56:36.820414 INFO: Starting processing
panic: Error parsing Kafka version: invalid version \`\`
goroutine 1 \[running\]:
log.Panicf({0x1229727?, 0xc000044480?}, {0xc000307c28?, 0x1058ae0?, 0xc000053500?})
/snap/go/10554/src/log/log.go:439 +0x65
```

Comment: Please show where the version input parameter comes from

Comment: ``` var (
 brokers  = config.Of.Kafka.Brokers
 version  = config.Of.Kafka.Version
 group    = config.Of.Kafka.Group
 topics   = config.Of.Kafka.Topic
 assignor = config.Of.Kafka.Assignor
 oldest   = config.Of.Kafka.Oldest
 verbose  = config.Of.Kafka.Verbose
 delay    = config.Of.Kafka.Delay
) ```


this one

Comment: Please show the actual value. The error seems to say it's an empty string